# ios json parsing sub collection

Tags: ios, json

I have a json collection I am able to parse perfectly fine 1 level deep, but each item in the main collection has a collection in it.  I am not quite sure how to access 'item' to get the sub collection like I did with the main collection...

```
NSString *response = [request responseString];
NSDictionary *json = [response JSONValue];

NSArray *items = [json valueForKeyPath:@"item"];

for (id item in items) 
{
    mainObject.name = [item objectForKey:@"name"];  //this works fine
    // How do I get sub collection from item?
}
```

Some of the json:

```
{"item":
    { 
      "available_at"     : null,
      "created_at"       : "2011-12-09T19:52:23Z",
      "lo_id"            : 30,
      "id"               : 24,
      "merchant_id"      : 1,
      "order_id"         : 25,
      "reach_local_link" : null,
      "status"           : null,
      "token"            : "12-258847891-1",
      "updated_at"       : "2011-12-09T19:52:23Z",
      "url"              : "api/dir/v1/item/12-258847891-1/print",
      "subitem1"         :
          {
             "area"      : "local",
             "broker_id" : "",
             "broker_id" : null,
             "category"  :
                 {
                     "category":....
```

In the example, there could be multiple sub items like subitem1.  I need to get the collection of those and have another for loop inside the current one.

Comment: Include a little bit of what your JSON looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item` will simply be a dictionary or array if it is one in the JSON object. For example, you should be able to do this:

```
NSDictionary *subitem1 = [item objectForKey:@"subitem1"];
```

It's simply a `NSDictionary` in there, so you can use it as one.

I really recommend logging the Objective-C representation of your JSON object, it makes it easier to work with it:

```
NSLog(@"%@", json);
```

**Warning**
It's strongly recommended to check the type of the objects you load before assuming that they really are dictionaries, strings or arrays. If they aren't, you'll notice that your application is going to crash.

Comment: Yeah I did play around earlier and figured out how to load subitem1 into a dictionary, but that only gives me key/value pairs of all the items inside subitem1.  What I need is the array of subitem1's.  Yes I do NSLog all that stuff...I just condensed my example for ease of reading

Comment: You can iterate through the keys of a NSDictionary: `for (NSString *key in subitem1) NSLog(@"%@: %@", key, [subitem1 objectForKey:key]);`

Comment: Actually, subitem1 would really be subitem, and each sub item would be "subitem".  So just as I have an NSArray of items, I need an NSArray of subitem

Comment: The same applies. They are normal NSArrays and NSDictionaries.

Comment: Again, getting the dictionary is only giving me the dictionary of the key/value pairs of the first item in the collection.  Lets say there are 3 subitem's: "subitem", "subitem", "subitem".  If I do NSDictionary *subitem1 = [item objectForKey:@"subitem"]; it is only going to give me a dictionary of the first subitems contents.

Comment: Then I would recommend getting a better JSON structure.

Comment: @Jesse The json example you provide does not contain an array.  If it really does then try using NSArray instead of NSDictionary.  Also, run your json through http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com